# PhpStorm 2020.3.1 JS inspection problem for some objects

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

In PhpStorm 2020.3.1, there were problems with the inspection of JavaScript code:

> Unresolved variable or type document

[image: code sample]

How can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that **HTML** predefined library is enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**;
if this doesn't help, and the issue persists after caches invalidation (**File > Invalidate caches/Restart, Invalidate and restart**), check what file type the `*.ts` pattern is assigned to in **Settings | Editor | File Types** - it has to be **TypeScript** and not **TypoScript** or any other files type

Comment: I followed all the recommendations, but the problem persists